# Add margin top to a DIV without affecting another DIV

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my site I have 2 DIVs, side by side.  The first one to the right contains text while the one on the left contains an image.  I need to add a `margin-top: 5%;` to the first DIV. When I do so, this margin is also applied to the one on the right.  I have doubled checked my code, and it looks fine to me.

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

This is what is happening:

[image]

Here's my code

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.como-funciona-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.como-funciona-device {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.como-funciona-device img {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.como-funciona-text {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.como-funciona-text h5 {
  font-size: 2.7em;
  color: #2c2c2c;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.como-funciona-text p {
  margin-top: 2%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="como-funciona-container" style="border: 1px solid;">
      <div class="como-funciona-text" style="border: 1px solid;">
        <h5>¿Cómo funciona?</h5>
        <p>Con solo leer el código QR que SimpleCash genera puedes recibir, pagar y retirar tus fondos. Ahora tendrás tu dinero de forma virtual en tu celular y podrás realizar transacciones de forma rápida y segura.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="como-funciona-device" style="border: 1px solid;">
        <img src="img/screen-qr.png" alt="Aplicación SimpleCash">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <body>
```

Comment: I think you want it to be displayed vertically center. Can you just add codepen for it. I can try it there and fix it

Comment: Actually, that already worked! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Sandip Nirmal commented above, all I had to do was add `vertical-align: middle;` to my CSS.